# Dividing set of integers

Tags: algorithm, divide, partition-problem

I've got a problem with a solution for algorithmic problem as described below.

We have a set (e.g. array) of integers. Our task is to divide them into the groups (they don't have to have same amount of elements) that sum is equal to each other. I case that primal set cannot be divide we have to give answer "impossible to divide".

For example:
Set `A` is given `[-7 3 3 1 2 5 14]`. The answer is `[-7 14], [3 3 1], [2 5]`.

It seems that it's easy to say when for sure it would be impossible. When sum of primal set isn't divisible by 3: `sum(A) % 3 != 0`.

Do you have any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Do you have to partition the given array into 3 pieces? Also, what solution complexity are you looking for?

Comment: A trivial solution is to simply return the original set!

Comment: The solution is impossible even if we cannot divide into 3 such sets. For example, {1000, 1001, 1002, 3} has a sum divisible by 3 but the division into subsets with equal sums is impossible.

Comment: @user1952500: that's not what Pączek said. If the sum is *not* evenly divisible by the number of sets, then you are *sure* it's not possible. The question is, what if it is?

Comment: @Jongware The first statement did not say that. The second was what you said.

Comment: Surely the problem is to find *all* such groupings, otherwise as @Rafe says, the identity function would suffice.

Comment: @Rafe Haha, that would be an answer but I forgot to mention that we have to partition array to 3 pieces. And we don't need to find all solutions. It's necessary to find at least one or to say that it's impossible to partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [3-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) variant of the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), the difference being that the classic partition problem splits the set into two sets (not three) whose sums are equal to each other.  This problem is NP-complete, so you're almost certainly not going to find a polynomial time solution for it; the 2-partition problem has a pseudopolynomial time solution, but the 3-partition problem does not.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4804123/1827903) for an outline of how to adapt the 2-partition algorithm to a 3-partition algorithm. See also [this paper](http://www.ijrte.org/attachments/File/v2i1/F0409021613.pdf) for a parallel solution.

Comment: Thank you @Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot! I hadn't knew the partition problem so I didn't know about what should I ask;) Both linked, answer and paper, I've found very useful and interesting.