# What's the recursion formula in the following code to solve the 3-Partition Problem in DP method

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I have a python code which solves the [3-Partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803668/3-partition-problem) using Dynamic Programming method. But I don't really understand how he utilizes the DP method. Could anyone tell me what is the recursion formula in this code and why it works? (Especially the middle loop part)

```
import sys
def partition3(A):
   n = len(A)
   if sum(A)%3 != 0:
       return 0
   W = sum(A)//3
   value = [[[0 for x in range(W+1)] for y in range(W+1)] for z in range(len(A)+1)]
   #print("dimension,n:",len(value[0][0]), len(A))
   value[0][0][0] = 1
   for idx in range(len(A)+1):
       value[idx][0][0] = 1

   for i in range(1, n+1):
       for j in range(W+1):
           for k in range(W+1):
            
             value[i][j][k] = value[i-1][j][k]
             
             if (j >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j-A[i-1]][k]):

                value[i][j][k] = 1
             if (k >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j][k-A[i-1]]):
                value[i][j][k] = 1
   for idx in range(n+1):
        print(value[idx][0][:])
   if(value[len(A)][W][W] == 1):
        return 1
   else:
        return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
   input = sys.stdin.read()
   n, *A = list(map(int, input.split()))
   print(partition3(A))
```

Comment: The recursive formula corresponds to this part: `value[i][j][k] = value[i-1][j][k]
             
             if (j >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j-A[i-1]][k]):

                value[i][j][k] = 1
             if (k >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j][k-A[i-1]]):
                value[i][j][k] = 1`

Comment: Which is somewhat awkward in my opinion, and could be rewritten with logic operators: `value[i][j][k] = value[i-1][j][k] or (j >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j-A[i-1]][k]) or (k >= A[i-1] and value[i-1][j][k-A[i-1]])`

Comment: There are a few weird things in the code you pasted. For instance, it uses `1` and `0` instead of `True` and `False`. The final four lines are redundant: `if(value[len(A)][W][W] == 1): return 1 else: return 0` is equivalent to `return value[len(A)][W][W]`

Comment: Hi Stef! Thank you for your explanation and improvement. I just don’t understand what is the meaning of this recursion formula. What is the math background behind this, could you explain this to me? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm afraid I'll say something false. The code you pasted doesn't explain the meaning of variables i, j and k in `value[i][j][k]`. From the dimensions of `value`, I assume `j` represents the sum of the first part in a 3-partition, `k` represents the sum of the second part (the sum of the third part must be `3*W - j - k`); and `i` represents... a number of used elements of `A`?

Comment: Oh. `i` is in `range(len(A)+1)`, but we always refer to `A[i-1]`, never to `A[i]`. So from this we can guess that `i` is never 0 (otherwise `A[i-1]` is `A[-1]` which is technically allowed, but would be super weird). So I'm guessing `i` simply represents the index of an element of `A`, and whoever wrote this code decided to use 1-indexes instead of 0-indexes, though that's a bit awkward in python.